# Will creating a Messaging Service within Twilio to connect to Salesforce affect a pre-existing Zoho implementation?

Tags: salesforce, twilio, zoho

Working on an implementation moving from Zoho to Salesforce. As part of the build for the Salesforce integration, we are required to build a Messaging Service in Twilio (this was not needed in Zoho). Will the creation of the Messaging Service impact the pre-existing Zoho implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware, of these two configuration aspects:

Messaging Services Defer to Sender's Webhook Option now available

https://www.twilio.com/changelog/messaging-services-defer-to-senders-webhook-option-now-available

Do I have to use a Messaging Service?

https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/a2p-10dlc/onboarding#do-i-have-to-use-a-messaging-service